# Chef manage UI gives a blank page

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef. I have installed chef server 12.4.1 in an RHEL5 server and chef-manage rpm as well. I am getting the login screen and able to register a user. After logging in I am getting a blank page. Ivan also see certificate warning in the browser. I am using IE11. I noticed the chef-server.rb and I chef-manage.rb are empty. Any help on this is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` and [`chef-manage-ctl reconfigure`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_manage.html) (if that command is not available, try `opscode-manage-ctl reconfigure`. Further, please [check the server logs](https://docs.chef.io/server_logs.html).

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for your reply. I ran chef-server-ctl reconfigure, chef-manage-ctl reconfigure and ops ode-manage-ctl reconfigure successfully without any errors. Also /var/log/chef-manage/web/current shows no errors. The login is successful and the next page after login is a black colour empty page.

Answer (score 0):

Chef Manage is not really related to Chef. It's a product of Chef Software Inc. A support contract is included with your subscription and you can reach them at support@chef.io.

Comment: Finally the issue got fixed. It was due to the browser compatibility in IE11. The issue is fixed by removing the check mark from IE11 Settings-> Compatibility view settings -> Display intranet sites in Compatibility View